# how to get suggestiongs with spring_data_solr?

Tags: autosuggest, spring-data-solr

I can get the result I want when I query in the administration console like below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X46N.png)

But how can I get the response in spring_data_solr? I tried to use SpellcheckPage to receive the result, but somehow I couldn't get the suggestions I want.

The query like below:
http://localhost:8080/solr/index.htmltest/suggest?indent=on&q=a&wt=json
and when query in the administration console I could get the response I want.
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2196},
  "suggest":{"mySuggester":{
      "a":{
        "numFound":4,
        "suggestions":[{
            "term":"abcd",
            "weight":1,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"abef",
            "weight":1,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"abes",
            "weight":1,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"aeg",
            "weight":1,
            "payload":""}]}}}} 
.But in spring_data_solr 2.1.4, how can I receive the result? I tried to use SpellcheckPage but can't get the suggestions I want. Solr version is 6.6.

Comment: Please add more details. What does the actual query look like? Who do you  retrieve the `SpellecheckedPage`? How far does the result not meet your expectations? Which version of Spring Data Solr are you using? Which version of Solr are you using....

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Christoph Strobl. I add more details in the desc. I think the question is how to receive the response I get .